# Firebase-admin with Typescript rejects all FieldValues

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using `firebase-admin` to control a firestore database using Cloud Functions with TypeScript. If I set the type of my collection reference, I can no longer `add` using `FieldValue`s. The argument types from `add` require a literal object matching the collection document, without any `FieldValue`s. What is a supported pattern for using `FieldValue`s with `firebase-admin` in TypeScript? Any answer using the base libraries with `FieldValue`s will do.

Here is a minimal example with `FieldValue.serverTimestamp`:

```
import { firestore, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin'
import { firebaseConfig } from './secret'
import { https } from 'firebase-functions'

interface User {
  id?: string
  displayName: string
  createdAt: firestore.Timestamp
}
const converter = {
  toFirestore: (data: User) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snapshot: firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<User>): User => {
    const data = snapshot.data()
    const doc = { id: snapshot.id, ...data }
    return doc
  }
}
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = firestore()
const usersCollectionRef = db.collection('users').withConverter(converter)
export const cloudFunction = https.onCall(async (props, context) => {
  const newUserData = {
    displayName: 'New User',
    createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  }
  await usersCollectionRef.add(newUserData)
  // Argument of type '{ displayName: string; createdAt: firestore.FieldValue; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
  // Types of property 'createdAt' are incompatible.
  // Type 'FieldValue' is missing the following properties from type 'Timestamp': seconds, nanoseconds, toDate, toMillis
})
```

Similarly, with `FieldValue.arrayUnion`:

```
interface User {
  id?: string
  friendNames: string[]
}
const converter = {
  toFirestore: (data: User) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snapshot: firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<User>): User => {
    const data = snapshot.data()
    const doc = { id: snapshot.id, ...data }
    return doc
  }
}
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = firestore()
const usersCollectionRef = db.collection('users').withConverter(converter)
export const cloudFunction = https.onCall(async (props, context) => {
  await usersCollectionRef.add({
    friendNames: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('BFF')
    // Type 'FieldValue' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'

interface UserType {
  id?: string
  displayName: string
  createdAt: Timestamp
  // update
  friends: string[]
}

....

// creates a firestore hanlder
export const firestore = Object.assign(
  () => {
    return admin.firestore()
  }, {
    doc: <T>( path: string ) => {
      return admin.firestore()
        .doc( path )
        .withConverter<T>( converter<T>() )
    },
    collection: <T>( path: string ) => {
      return admin.firestore()
        .collection( path )
        .withConverter<T>( converter<T>() )
    },
    // update
    fieldValue: admin.firestore.FieldValue
  } )
// typed converter
const converter = <T>() => ( {
  toFirestore: ( data: any ) => data,
  fromFirestore: ( doc: any ) => {
    return {
       ...doc.data(),
       id: doc.id
    } as T
  }
} )
```

then use it like this:

```
import {firestore} from 'some/place'

...

// you can now have types while setting and getting data
const usersRef = firestore.collection<UserType>('/users')
await userRef.add({
  displayName: 'New User',
  // update
  createdAt: firestore.fieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  friends: firestore.fieldValue.arrayUnion('FRIEND_NAME')
})
```

Comment: This does not allow the use of `FieldValue`s as the question requires. I don't want to use `Date.now`, I want to use the `FieldValue` for things like `serverTimestamp`, but also `increment` or `arrayUnion`. All of these operations require `FieldValue`. I tried implementing the converters exactly as you describe, and changed my `add` to `doc.set` to try, but the same error occurs if you attempt to use a `FieldValue` for `createdAt`. Do you know away to use `FieldValue`?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope this fit your needs

Comment: I tried the updated version but the same error is given.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define `createdAt` as `Timestamp` Type

```
import type { Timestamp } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

interface User {
  displayName: string
  createdAt: Timestamp
}
```

I believe this should fix the problem

Comment: I tried this, but the same basic error is there. I updated the question to use `Timestamp`.

Comment: Hey @DavidY.Stephenson try these ugly fixes.
`newUserData = {
    displayName: 'New User',
    createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  } as User // or as unknown as User.`

Comment: And regrading the ArrayUnion, Its better to define its type as string[] | firebase.firestore.FieldValue, Because return type of of ArrayUnion is [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-arrayunion), Further you can take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2008).
Hope this solves your problems :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I wish to avoid these `as` fixes because then I cannot rely on the types for developing. Defining an optional FieldValue doesn't use the types to check the `FieldValue`, as `increment` cannot be used on array values, etc. I will check the issue you linked, thanks.

Comment: The solution of duplicating types described in the solution prevents reading the values correctly, as Firestore never returns `FieldValue`s.

Comment: Hmm yes Firestore itself never return FieldValue but using `FieldValue`'s arrayunion func does so the Type issue persists, I don't think there is clever way to circumvent the type issue (only with using `as` fixes so far). Maybe when Microsoft introduces GPT model to typescript type scene then it might not give the error haha.